# Minecraft Java Simple Raid farm goes directly to "win" - raiders unable to spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I basically want the kids playing on our server to be able to get new Totems of undying and Hero of the Village V easily. I have a stacking raid farm, but that requires more planning to use, so I'm now trying to create something easy and fast.

So I'm trying to hook a simple raid farm up to my bad omen farm, but I can't get the raiders to spawn. The raid starts and after a short while the raid bar empties and I get "Raid victory" without getting the hero of the village. Can anyone help with what changes I need to get the pillagers spawning?

I've built the farm up in the air to avoid any other spawns. My killing chamber is at Y 210, and the spawning plattform is at 236. The main spawning plattform should now be 32x32.

Minecraft java 1.18.2

PaperMC server build 295

[image: Overview of farm]
[image: Sideview of farm]